# Loop through entities chosen by Views Bulk Operations

Tags: views

I successfully created a new action using hook_action_info() and a corresponding hook_action(). However, I want to find the method which loops through the elements chosen by Views Bulk Operations, as I wanted to combine some pages for a pdf.

What method loops through the entities chosen by VBO?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the [VBO Development guide](https://drupal.org/node/459070), you can use the `aggregate` option to get a list of all chosen entities.

> **implement hook_action_info()**
>
> ***aggregate (optional)***: boolean. If TRUE, all selected objects' IDs
>   (oids) will be packed in an array and passed as the first argument to
>   the action function, instead of passing each object one by one. This
>   is useful to implement aggregate functions that perform a single
>   operation on the whole selection set.

Note this guide is only for D6. I have created a [D7 version](https://drupal.org/node/2052067) but could not add an aggregate example yet.

However, in your hook_action_info() implementation, set `aggregate` to TRUE (defaults to FALSE) and VBO will send a list of entity IDs (for you to perform additional related tasks).